# Using VBA to fill out an email template into one cell in excel

Tags: excel, vba

For my job, I need to send a multi paragraph email to client, using a basic template that has different coloured text and bold and hyper links. There are things like the name, invoice and account number that get filled out right now by using an excel sheet and word mail merge. It’s a shared email address with the rest of my team so I don’t want to directly email from this. I want to copy and paste by clicking on a cell in and pasting into my outlook client while maintaining all formatting. Is there a script I could make that would take inputs listed above and output my email with proper formatting into one cell?

I am currently using mail merge to fill out a word document but it takes a while to copy and paste the multiple page doc into outlook. I have tried to use current cell formulas but from my last two hours of reading it seems impossible to maintain the colour text formatting which is required.

Comment: A single cell can't contain multiple hyperlinks, or a hyperlink on only part of its text.